# clamxav homebrew mac os x

Tags: macos, homebrew

On Mac OS X 10.6.8 I just installed Homebrew. It broke ClamXav. So I uninstalled it, and installed Homebrew's clamav. At the end of the installation process I received this:

/ `Warning: /usr/local/sbin is not in your PATH 
You can amend this by altering your ~/.bashrc file`

I don't know what I'm supposed to do next? What path am I supposed amend from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
```

(OS X get's your path from those files. If the first one exists it grabs that path then it moves on to the next file to get more information and so on... For more information go to: http://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashrc.html

Look for `~/.bash_profile` etc... until you see where your path is set. MOST of the time your path is normally set in `~/.bash_profile` so check that file first and if it's not in there but in another, change it over to `~/.bash_profile`

It is possible that none of these files exists in which case homebrew will complain when you run command `brew doctor` that /usr/local/bin is not ahead of /usr/bin/. Edit your `~/.bash_profile` to satisfy both homebrew and clamxav.

To make things as simple as possible and fix your problem, locate `~/.bash_profile` and:

No path or no `~/.bash_profile`: If you have no Path, open or create the file and input the following line: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`

If you need to create the file you can do so with terminal.app or even textedit but i would suggest terminal.

1. Open Terminal.app -> when prompted run: `cd ~` to get to your home directory although you should be there.
2. `touch .bash_profile` which creates the empty file.
3. `pico .bash_profile` -> Now at this screen paste: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`
4. Once you've inserted the path simply press the Key: `Enter` to save and `Control + X` to exit. -> lastly you might as well update bash with the command: `source .bash_profile`

If `~/.bash_profile` exists with a path but /usr/local/sbin is not included, add it by  appending `/usr/local/sbin/` to any part, probably a good idea to put it after `/usr/local/bin:` directories are separated by semi-colons. Make sure to keep the format consistent.

To make sure /usr/local/sbin is in your path open terminal and run: `echo $PATH` you should see /usr/local/sbin somewhere in the output.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and just to add to Bobs answer, I found that the line `usr/local/sbin` had to be added to `/etc/paths`

Thats running OS X 10.7.4

Comment: This also works with Mountain Lion 10.8.2 + homebrew + rabbitmq.

Comment: Interesting, I am not familiar with rabbitmq, but homebrew does not neeed or want you to modify system files to make it work. Hence the no-sudo necessary clause. //usr/local/sbin is not included in your paths file(/etc/paths/) by default so unless your project only reads /etc/paths/ and then doesn't go deeper I would add (...)/sbin/ to your path without altering system files, i.e. /etc/* - For those of you who do edit sys files you might be happy to know that whatever order the paths are in /etc/paths/ are how they appear to the shell. Move the bottom to the top and it's frontmost. just a tip.