# Where do I find the bashrc file on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

Hello I am following this [page](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/).. I'm installing Python onto my mac so that I can set up a `Django / Eclipse` development environment. However I am not too sure how to go about executing this step:

> - The script will explain what changes it will make and prompt you
>   before the installation begins.

- Once you’ve installed Homebrew,
  insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable.
- You can do this by adding the following line at the bottom of your
  **~/.bashrc file**

> - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Where do I find the bashrc file on my mac and where do I find the homebrew directory?

I am running a `macbook` pro with `OS 10.8.5`.

Comment: `find / -name \*bashrc\*`. Plus, it tells you exactly where: `~/.bashrc`, where `~` is Unix short-hand for "user's home directory".

Comment: In `~/.bashrc`. `~` is an abbreviation for your homedir that the shell understands.

Comment: If you don't have `.bashrc` in your homedir you have to create it yourself :)

Comment: i dont think this was off topic and am glad i found it here

Comment: As the question is about setting up development tools (python) it's on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The .bashrc file is in your home directory.

So from command line do:

```
cd
ls -a
```

This will show all the hidden files in your home directory. "cd" will get you home and ls -a will "list all".

In general when you see ~/ the tilda slash refers to your home directory. So ~/.bashrc is your home directory with the .bashrc file.

And the standard path to homebrew is in /usr/local/ so if you:

```
cd /usr/local
ls | grep -i homebrew
```

you should see the homebrew directory (/usr/local/homebrew). [Source](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation)

Yes sometimes you may have to create this file and the typical format of a .bashrc file is:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions
. .alias
alias ducks='du -cks * | sort -rn | head -15'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/homebrew
export PATH
```

If you create your own .bashrc file make sure that the following line is in your ~/.bash_profile

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Thanks I tried `ls ~/.bashrc` but it says No such file or directory. Do I have to create it from scratch?

Comment: This answer helped me figure it out. and this comment will update the thread. 
I am on mac SierraOS
found it '/etc/bashrc'     ... the system wide bashrc was not hidden .bashrc.      


to manipulate it I had to 'sudo vi bashrc'
to exit after editing:         :wq!


... full command     'cd /etc/; sudo vi bashrc'

Comment: typically $PATH is at the end and customer directories at the start. That allows you to choose alternatives to system commands.  PATH=/home/username/bin:/usr/local/homebrew:$PATH

Comment: Rather than /home/username perhaps use $HOME for a more flexible approach, so you don't need to change the username for a different user.

Comment: The other answer of just using .bash_profile is much quicker and simpler.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDOVEDl2z84 This video explains and illustrate .bashrc and .bash_profile

Answer (score 65):

I would think you should add it to `~/.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`, (creating `.bash_profile` if it doesn't exist.) Then you don't have to add the extra step of checking for `~/.bashrc` in your `.bash_profile`

Are you comfortable working and editing in a terminal? Just in case, `~/` means your home directory, so if you open a new terminal window that is where you will be "located". And the dot at the front makes the file invisible to normal `ls` command, unless you put `-a` or specify the file name.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278352/1681480) for more detail.

Comment: I get the following `Shajilhost:~ ShajilShocker$ sudo ~/.bash_profile
Password:
sudo: /Users/ShajilShocker/.bash_profile: command not found` could you please help me

Comment: You have to use some kind of editor like `nano` or open it on your desktop. So it would be `nano ~/.bash_profile`  The `sudo` command just runs whatever command follows it as a superuser, so you were trying to use the file name as a command (which is why it says "command not found").

Comment: My intention is to create environment variable KEY is `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` and VALUE is `/Users/ShajilShocker/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10b`  ...so now I have to open the terminal and ` nano .bash_profile` and enter `ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/Users/ShajilShocker/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10b"` am i correct ? or add the following line as well `export PATH=$PATH:ANDROID_NDK_HOME` correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I believe the first would be sufficient and correct, but haven't tried the Android SDK...

Answer (score 16):

On your Terminal:

- Type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder.
- Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file.
- Edit *.bash_profile* with your code editor (or you can just type
  `open -e .bash_profile` to open it in TextEdit).
- Type `. .bash_profile` to reload *.bash_profile* and update any
  functions you add.

Comment: `. . bash_profile ` didn't work for me, still got **"no such file or directory: .bash_profile"**. then I did this `source ~/.bash_profile` and the `.bash_profile` was reloaded

Comment: This works fine, but then I have to do `source ~/.bash_profile` after each reboot. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 16):

In my macOS Monterey version, `zsh` is the default terminal shell. zsh executes ~/.zshrc every time the terminal is opened.

```
vi ~/.zshrc
#Add your path export to .zshrc
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Now, when you open the terminal, the path will be set correctly.

Comment: This is the answer which worked for me in 2022

Answer (score 6):

On some system, instead of the .bashrc file, you can edit your profils' specific by editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 4):

The .bash_profile for macOS is found in the `$HOME` directory. You can create the file if it does not exit. Sublime Text 3 can help.

- If you follow the instruction from [OS X Command Line - Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) to launch ST3 with `subl` then you can just do this

  ```
  $ subl ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- An easier method is to use `open`

  ```
  $ open ~/.bash_profile -a "Sublime Text"
  ```

Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> in Finder to view hidden files in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

`~/.bashrc` is already a path to `.bashrc`.

If you do `echo ~` you'll see that it's a path to your home directory.

Homebrew directory is `/usr/local/bin`. Homebrew is installed inside it and everything installed by homebrew will be installed there.

For example, if you do `brew install python` Homebrew will put Python binary in `/usr/local/bin`.

Finally, to add Homebrew directory to your path you can run `echo "export PATH=/usr/local/lib:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc`. It will create `.bashrc` file if it doesn't exist and then append the needed line to the end.

You can check the result by running `tail ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal and execute commands given below.

```
cd /etc
subl bashrc
```

subl denotes Sublime editor. You can replace **subl** with **vi** to open bashrc file in default editor. This will workout only if you have bashrc file, created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to home directory of your user: `cd ~/`
2. list all hidden files in the directory and locate: `.zprofile`
3. Edit the file in vi and enter your alias in it at the end of the file.
   Eg: `alias ll='ls -lart'`
4. Save and exit the file.
5. Run the command: `source .zprofile`
6. Run the command: `ll`. You will see the alias working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to home directory of your user: cd ~/
list all hidden files in the directory using: ls -a
locate the file: .zprofile
Edit the file in vi and enter your alias in it at the end of the file.
Eg: alias ll='ls -lart'
Save with: wq:
Run the command: source .zprofile
Run the command: ll. You will see the alias working.