# Installing Homebrew

Tags: python, bash, homebrew

I have been searching for answers for the past hour, but all explanations seem to be given under the assumption that its readers are not total noobs, which I am. So please don't tell me this answer has been posted somewhere, everyone seems to be saying different things.

I'm trying to follow [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) tutorial. If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac), there is someone else doing what I'm doing with the same mac version (10.8.5) and everything.

So I have to create the .bashrc file seeing as it does not exist at my ~ location (which wasn't mentioned in the tutorial at all, so I probably slipped up at this point). So I went into textEdit and created an empty .bashrc file, and just added

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

like it says to in the tutorial. Then I move on to the next step:

```
$ brew install python
```

and I get "command not found". So this is my question – **why didn't this work?** I assume it has to do with my .bashrc file being empty. So I tried filling my .bashrc file with what Peter Party Bus instructed to do ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac)), but I'm not sure his "typical format of a .bashrc file" is word-for-word exactly what needs to go in it. And then Peter Party Bus goes on to say that I need to put some stuff in "~/.bash_profile"... I don't have that either! Should I just add that code into .profile instead? *(I don't have enough rep to comment directly on his answer.)* So many questions... Thanks in advance, again sorry for being noob.

**Edit, solved:**
Syntax error. Was typing

```
$ brew install python
```

instead of

```
brew install python
```

Thanks Blender

Comment: ["Homebrew"](http://brew.sh/) is a separate software package with its own installer. It looks like you are trying to install Python. Have you installed Homebrew first?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the tutorial page I posted, I followed all the instructions (installing homebrew was the first step)

Comment: Did you run `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"` first?

Comment: Have you opened and closed Terminal or tried running `source ~/.bashrc`? Your PATH won't update automatically.

Comment: Yup... "==> Installation successful!" @ sortfiend

Comment: What do you get from `which brew`?

Comment: i typed `source ~/.bashrc` and nothing happened (even after re-opening terminal)... @Blender

Comment: /usr/local/bin/brew @sortfiend

Comment: @user1757149: Nothing should happen on screen. Try running `brew` once more and see if the executable is found.

Comment: @Blender: By "running `brew`" do you mean `$ brew install python`? Tried that and got "command not found" again.

Comment: @user1757149: Now are you literally running `$ brew install python`, or just `brew install python`?

Comment: @Blender including the $.

Comment: omfg. Left out the $ and there we go... I'm gonna go cry now. Thanks Blender.

Comment: @user1757149: Well, there's your problem.

Comment: An FYI... OSX will automatically things in `.profile` when you create a new terminal, but not `.bashrc`.  You can either put `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in your `.profile` instead, or put `test -e ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` in your `.profile` so you don't have to do it manually.