# How to set NDK Build path in OSX for Android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, terminal, android-ndk

I had set the `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` as `/Users/Shajilshocker/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10b` using a mac osx application called ***Environment Variables***.

I had confirmed that it set the path correctly in Terminal

`echo $ANDROID_NDK_HOME`

But when I run a shell file in a Android Studio project which invokes `ndk-build` I get the following error

`ndk-build: command not found`

How to make sure that ndk-build is in your build path ?

How to set ndk-build in my build path ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Two things: Are you sure that this directory is the correct one? `ndk-build` is directly in this directory. Secondly, what shell file are you running exactly?

Comment: I am trying to run this file https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/blob/master/main/misc/build-native.sh

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, this is actually not enough to make the system aware of the path. You must add this path to the `PATH` system variable. In your case, all you have to do is to add the following line to your terminal configuration file (which should be under your home directory, named `.bashrc` if you kept the default terminal, full path: `~/.bashrc`):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Shajilshocker/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10b
```

What this line does is actually adding the path to your Android NDK directory to the `PATH` variable. You export a variable named `PATH` with its current content plus the directory of your NDK.

Step by step:

- Go in the home directory
- Edit `.bashrc`
- Add the line I showed above
- Save, exit, then restart bash (you just have to type `bash`, then enter)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question I have some doubts ...Consider I have uninstalled the application Environment Variables...Can you give me the steps from begining...My NDK builder is at /Users/Shajilshocker/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10b ..Now I have opened the terminal what are the next steps ?

Comment: `~/ ` means go in home directory to edit `.bashrc` ..when I try `~/ .bashrc` I get no such file or directory.

Comment: Later I found there is not `/bashrc` using this command ls -a which showed there is a `.bash_profile` and `.bash_history` so I thought lets edit it ` sudo ~/.bash_profile` But this is what I got ` command not found`  Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19664882/3856173 ..I hope you can help me

Comment: No, you must edit this file, it's not a command that you must execute. For example, you should type `nano .bashrc`. Try to create the file, add this line, and try again. If it doesn't work, add the line mentioned in this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/147699/243369) to get it to work.

Comment: I will try and let u know...oneupvote for your effort..if works I'll accept your post as answer

Comment: Hi @JBL Where is .bashrc file on MAC OS. I go to Home directory > go to User > Maidul ISlam> There is no .bashrc visible file. How can I find that. Please let me know.

Comment: @Maid786 The `.bashrc` file should be in your home directory (a.k.a. `~`). If it  isn't, you can create it yourself. Please also consider that this may depend on your shell. For example, if you're using `zsh`, the file you want to edit is `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Note that if you installed the NDK from Android Studio's built-in SDK manager/tools, than the path would be `/Users/_username_/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`

Answer (score 30):

For mac use this: Open your .bash_profile file with a text editor. .bash_profile is by default found in home directory. Eg /Users/john

the assumption is: you have downloaded the android sdk and ndk to /User/john/Android or you can find the path from Android Studio by going to

Project Structure > SDK Location, pay attention to Android SDK location & Android NDK location

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/john/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=/Users/john/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"
```

Then save the above lines to your .bash_profile file. Close it and try typing this on your terminal

```
ndk-build
```

if the response is like below, you are good to go

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
/Users/john/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-local.mk:143: ***   Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

The assumption here is you have downloaded your android sdk to /Users/john/Android

Comment: Hi @James Bond Where is .bashrc file on MAC OS. I go to Home directory > go to User > Maidul ISlam> There is no .bashrc visible file. How can I find that. Please let me know.

Comment: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html the above link might be of help

Comment: Man...u r a genius.. It works.. Btw to all stalker out there , if it doesn't work then logout and login after changing bash_profile... and make sure that the ndk directory is within sdk. it tool for me several weeks to realise this truth

Answer (score 13):

In case this helps anyone, I installed the Android NDK using Android Studio on MacOS by following the instructions on the [android.com NDK webpage](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html#download-ndk): I selected Tools --> Android --> SDK Manager and then selected NDK. Android Studio then installed the downloaded files under:

```
/Users/user.name/Library/Android/sdk/
```

That directory is the same one that is listed on the SDK Manager window inside Android Studio. Underneath that directory is another directory `ndk-bundle`, which has all the NDK tools.

Thus, I added this to my path:

```
/Users/user.name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/
```

Answer (score 4):

- `cd` to path you have to set.
- Enter in *Terminal*: `echo "export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile`

Comment: After the system restart.I have to do this again.

Comment: `>> sudo file` is not valid syntax. You can, however, use `sudo tee -a` to do the same thing.