# Not getting graphics even when reinstalled Ocaml (Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, ocaml, macos-sierra

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435927/ocaml-unbound-graphics-module) I installed brew and then reinstalled ocaml to include graphics:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew cask install xquartz
brew reinstall ocaml --with-x11
```

But after restarting my computer, when I tried to run an ocaml program that used graphics I got the error

```
Error: Cannot find file /Users/.../.opam/4.03.0/lib/ocaml/graphics.cma
```

The post also said:

> Finally remember to check that the instance of ocaml that is running
>   is the one in `/usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/x.yy.z[_w]/bin`, and
>   if it isn't then prepend that url to your  `PATH` environment
>   variable.

How do I do check the instance of ocaml that is running? And what does the poster mean by "prepending that url to your  `PATH` environment"?

I've tried changing my directory to that path, but I get an error:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/
-bash: cd: /usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/: No such file or directory
```

If someone could please tell me what I need to do to get graphics.cma working that would be great!

---

### UPDATES:

I've tried creating `.bashrc` and putting in

```
alias ocaml="/usr/local/Cellar/ocaml/4.04.0/bin/ocaml”
```

Yet with no avail...I'm quite lost on what to do. If anyone could give me an inkling of what to do that would be great!

(Note: I put `4.04.0` instead of `4.03.0`because when I explored the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/ocaml/4.03.0/bin/ocaml` but the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/ocaml/4.04.0/bin/ocaml` does)

Comment: none of the documented fixes worked for me installing ocaml 4.06.0 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6. I left a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435927/ocaml-unbound-graphics-module) explaining what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I do check the instance of ocaml that is running?

If your question is: what program is running when you type `ocaml` in a terminal window at the shell prompt (or more generally thru [execvp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) and other functions)? then you should **use the `which ocaml` command**.

> And what does the poster mean by "prepending that url to your PATH environment"?

Read more about the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) variable. It is often set in your [`~/.bashrc` file](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file) (which you should probably and carefully edit once using your favorite [editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor)) -or some other bash initialization file- if your interactive shell is `bash`. You should check what it is with the `echo $PATH` command. See also [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/73965). Notice that `~/.bashrc` is [expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) by your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) during [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). Read also the documentation of `bash` notably the [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) chapter.

If you are using `opam` you should read its documentation. Notably [this question](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html#Whydoesopaminitneedtoaddstufftomyinitscriptswhyisevalopamconfigenvneeded) (mentioning `PATH`) from its FAQ.

Since aliases are mostly for interactive shells, defining an alias is not enough for most shell scripts. You really need to change your `$PATH` and/or add files (or symlinks) in directories mentioned in it.

<sup>PS. Understanding the role of `PATH` and how to set it is mandatory for serious use of the command line, notably on POSIX systems.</sup>

Comment: You probably need to edit your `~/.bashrc` file, but you also need to understand the content of that file before editing it. How exactly is your particular account set we cannot tell.

Comment: You don't need to locate it. It is in `~/.bashrc` that your shell expands like `$HOME/.bashrc`; so if your home directory is `/home/ongm` you need to edit `/home/ongm/.bashrc` with some editor (like `emacs` or `vim` or whatever editor you use). Perhaps running `open ~/.bashrc` might be enough to start an editor, but this is system specific.

Comment: okay i did `$ cd ~` then `$ ls -a` like this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac) said, but i don't see `.bashrc` listed...do i need create it?

Comment: I also don't see `.bash_profile`. I only see `.bash_history` and `.bash_sessions`

Comment: I don't know how your particular interactive `bash` shell is set up (and I don't know any MacOSX specific) and configured (that is system and computer specific). Probably you need to find out by yourself. I'm sure it is a FAQ.

Comment: alright. thanks for taking the time to answer my question, im glad that i've narrowed down the problem!

Comment: I added more links. I believe you should follow all of them. You are lacking some basic understanding about how your bash shell is working, and you need several hours to learn more about it. And understanding that is useful in general (not only for `opam` or `ocaml`)

Answer (score 1):

In general, **homebrew** puts all its binaries, libraries and settings in `/usr/local/Cellar/PACKAGENAME/VERSIONNUMBER` but it also creates symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` that point to the latest package/version.

So, if you look at my `/usr/local/bin` you will see:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin
```

**Output**

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        26 30 Jan  2016 ack -> ../Cellar/ack/2.14/bin/ack
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        43 11 Oct 13:30 amqp-consume -> ../Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.8.0/bin/amqp-consume
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        49 11 Oct 13:30 amqp-declare-queue -> ../Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.8.0/bin/amqp-declare-queue
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        48 11 Oct 13:30 amqp-delete-queue -> ../Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.8.0/bin/amqp-delete-queue
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        39 11 Oct 13:30 amqp-get -> ../Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.8.0/bin/amqp-get
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        43 11 Oct 13:30 amqp-publish -> ../Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.8.0/bin/amqp-publish
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        28 17 Jul 22:49 7z -> ../Cellar/p7zip/16.02/bin/7z
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        29 17 Jul 22:49 7za -> ../Cellar/p7zip/16.02/bin/7za
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin        29 17 Jul 22:49 7zr -> ../Cellar/p7zip/16.02/bin/7zr
lrwxr
```

As you can see, `ack` points to version 2.14 of `ack` in the Cellar and so on.

In general therefore, when using **homebrew**, you should not directly use anything in the Cellar because that is version-specific. Instead, you should use `/usr/local/bin` and rely on that pointing to the latest/greatest thing in the Cellar. That way you won't have pain when upgrading and you won't have to change all your `app-1.01` to `app-1.0.2` in all your scripts because you will just be using `app` (which, by virtue of your PATH, means `/usr/local/bin/app`) instead of anything version-specific.

So, I would suggest you edit your `bash` profile, using `TextEdit` like this:

```
open -e ~/.profile
```

and add this line at the end:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Remove all your version-specific aliases and log out and then back in again.