# Run executable in terminal vs open in mac finder

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a simple program that displays an image using OpenCV 4.3. If I run it in terminal e.g. `./test_opencv` it displays the image, however if I double-click the same executable in a Finder window, the read image is empty.

What is the cause of this?

I am including cmake 3.16, apple clang 11.0.3, and am including all opencv libraries.

Comment: Probably an assumption about the current working directory. If so try using an absolute path to your test image.

Comment: Both work with an absolute path. Looking in further `std::filesystem::current_path()` is the absolute path from where I call the executable in terminal and ~ if I run it through Finder. Any idea what the source of this is?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of it is working on terminal is that the program can reach the libraries which it needs. You should add the necessity libraries to environment by adding to `.bashrc` file.

Open terminal and find the all libraries which the program using by the command:

```
Ubuntu : ldd <path>

Mac: otool -L <path>
```

Then open bashrc and add the libraries which are not exist in there. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac) is the link for bashrc on mac. Also you should search what is **static library** and **dynamic library** means.

Comment: It is reaching the library. I am only adding opencv and get no errors calling cv::imread and calling member functions of the returned cv::Mat. If I try to display the empty image when launching through Finder, I get an opencv assert exception for the rows and cols being 0.