# How do I add the Anaconda path to the PATH environment on a Mac?

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

I have a macbook and I can't find any solutions to add the Anaconda path to the PATH environemnt online on my laptop. On Windows, you execute the installer file and this screen should show up. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boSnu.png)

Then, I have to click the Anaconda distribution folder when I click on "choose from list" button on Eclipse but I don't have that option displayed. [Supposed to look like pt. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6xEo.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4snju.png)

[What my screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0IEK.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

On mac/linux, you need to add env path by yourself.

Find your anaconda installed path and add commands in .zshrc or .bashrc

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Then, execute command `source ~/.zshrc` if you are using zsh.
Or, execute command `source ~/.bashrc` by default.

Comment: Can you explain how to find my anaconda installed path? I tried to execute the commands and nothing happened.

Comment: In mac, it might be installed in `/Users/{Your username}/opt/anaconda3` or `~/anaconda3`. Since everyone has different install environment, you need to find it by your own. I can only give you some tips, it might not be accurate.

Comment: I figured out my anaconda installed path, thank you!! When I executed the command source ~/.zshrc, it said __add_sys_prefix_to_path:6: command not found: dirname
__add_sys_prefix_to_path:7: command not found: dirname

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe clearly. For me, I use zsh for my terminal, so I modify the .zshrc file. And execute `source ~/.zshrc` for command activated.
If you are not using zsh, you may modify the `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file.
The file may not exist, just create one.

Comment: For more information about .bashrc, please refer [stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac)

Comment: done worry too much about the source ~./zshrc command just close and reopen your terminal it should work